# After booting from disk no wifi access appears only ethernet wired

Tags: wifi

I want to try elementary OS before installing so I booted from ISO disk Loki 0.4.1. After start up, there is no internet connection. when I click on the icon, the open window only shows a connection for wired Ethernet. when I try to add my ATT connection and password, the save button remains greyed-out and I cannot get the computer to recognize my wifi access point (or any Wifi) or connect. Currently running linux mint maya on an old DELL Inspiron 9400 and it is working pretty well. When I use `lshw -C network` in terminal when running mint it shows

```
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 00:16:cf:38:88:b3
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.248 (r487574) ip=192.168.1.70 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:17 memory:dfcfc000-dfcfffff memory:d0000000-d00fffff
```

Comment: I had the same problem with 0.4.1 but I had an old copy of 0.4.0 that worked fine after installing.

Answer (score 0):

In Terminal: `nm-connection-editor`. Add your new connection and also make it default: click Edit > General tab > check "Automatically connect to this network when it is available". Also, for the Ethernet connection which is present from the start: Edit > General tab > uncheck "Automatically connect to this network when it is available". Then connect to your newly added connection.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply and assistance. Tried this but it still won’t connect. I deleted the wired Ethernet option completely and it still won’t find the WiFi. Why is this so difficult and frustrating? Mint just finds the WiFi points and I just enter a password and go. Is it because I’m booting  from a disk and not an install?

Answer (score 0):

For card **BCM4321** you need follow this link

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx